# Linux: How to find out which process curently creates the most network traffic?

Tags: linux, networking, traffic

From time to time connection to my server is very slow. This could be that someone is doing large uploads or downloads. Since I have a lot of software on my server I would like to find out, which process is responsible for the traffic.

Is there a simple command which lists processes which are currently doing network communication, sorted by the amout of traffic that was created in the last x seconds?

My system is running Ubuntu.

Comment: Server operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this post on [AskUbuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/268581/how-to-check-if-any-background-process-is-utilizing-the-internet-connection)
This post explain installing and using iftop.

Comment: I hoped for on board tools. Can't beliefe such basic feature needs third party software.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like nethogs (http://nethogs.sourceforge.net/) or iftop (http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2008/12/iftop-guide-display-network-interface-bandwidth-usage-on-linux/).